# How to require system property only if task is executed?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle script with a custom test task:

```
task integrationTest(type:Test) {
  jvmArgs '-DmyParam=' + System.getProperty('myParam')
}
```

I want to fail the build with a nice message if the property is missing, but only if my task will be executed. I tried adding

```
task integrationTest(type:Test) {
  if (!System.hasProperty('myParam')) throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing property myParam")
  jvmArgs '-DmyParam=' + System.getProperty('myParam')
}
```

but this will fail even if the `integrationTest` task  isn't called.

How do I check this only when executing the task, instead of on gradle startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `doFirst` closure. The closure will be executed *before* the task action, so sufficiently early to modify the task, but not in *configuration phase*, but during *execution phase*, so, only if the task is executed:

```
task integrationTest(type:Test) {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs '-DmyParam=' + System.getProperty('myParam')
    }
}
```

Please note, that you can use the `systemProperty` method to define system properties:

```
systemProperty 'myParam', System.getProperty('myParam')
// instead of
jvmArgs '-DmyParam=' + System.getProperty('myParam')
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped me find the answer. Moving the exception to a `doFirst` block will produce the desired result:

```
task integrationTest(type:Test) {
    doFirst {
        if (!System.hasProperty('myParam')) throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing property myParam")
    }
    jvmArgs '-DmyParam=' + System.getProperty('myParam')
}
```

or, if you need to fail the build before any task is executed, you can check if the task will be called:

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { 
  if(project.gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(":integrationTest")) {
    if (!System.hasProperty('myParam')) throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing property myParam")
   }
}
```